# Query Relationship

Tags: sql, csv, datatable

I have csv file where I think I can convert to dataTable and todo the sql statement. As your can see my csv data like this below:-

```
date    time    person  visitor type
01/01   08:10   P001    V001    F
01/01   09:10   P002    V001    F
01/01   09:30   P002    V002    F
01/01   08:30   P003    V001    BF
01/01   08:45   P003    V003    F
01/01   08:50   P003    V004    BF
```

Ok. Honestly! My problem is I don't know how to create sql query statement to get output like this all below:-

1. By query visitor and person I can show their relations like this:-

   Select * where visitor="V001" and person="P001"

> ```
> 01/01 08:10   P001    V001    F
> 01/01 09:10   P002    V001    F
> 01/01 09:30   P002    V002    F
> ```

2. Another things I like to query to count each person have vistor like below:-

   Select ***** where count(visitor) => 2

   ```
   Person  Count
   P002    2
   P003    3
   ```

Thanks on advance fro reading and replying this question.

Thanks you.

Comment: Have you already converted the CSV Data to SQL Database?

Comment: Not yet.. I will find from this forums how to convert csv to data-table. My concern on creating query statement because I never face this assignment before. Many thanks for your reply and kindness.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from [TableName] where Visitor = 'V001' and Person = 'P001'
```

This query will output:

```
date    time    person  visitor type
01/01   08:10   P001    V001    F
```

```
Select * from [TableName] where Visitor = 'V001' or Person = 'P001'
```

This query will output:

```
date    time    person  visitor type
01/01   08:10   P001    V001    F
01/01   09:10   P002    V001    F
01/01   08:30   P003    V001    BF
```

```
Select Person,Count(Visitor) as Count from [TableName]  Group by
Person having Count(Visitor)>=2
```

This query will output:

```
Person  Count
P002    2
P003    3
```